# TypeORM in Electron cannot access the initialized data source on main process from preload

Tags: electron, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

TypeORM documentation states that `Generally, you call initialize method of the DataSource instance on application bootstrap, and destroy it after you completely finished working with the database. In practice, if you are building a backend for your site and your backend server always stays running - you never destroy a DataSource`.
I am initializing exported DataSource on Electron main process with app.whenReady() in the application bootstrap.

data-source.ts

```
export const dbContext = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'xxxxx',
  password: 'xxxxx',
  database: 'xxxxx',
  synchronize: false,
  logging: true,
  entities: [User],
  migrations: [InitialMigration1691999000003],
});
```

function in whenReady()

```
await dbContext.initialize();

await dbContext.runMigrations();

console.log("DB Connection Status", dbContext.isInitialized)
```

As I initialized the data source connection in the main process (application start), I should be able to use it in preload context bridge without initializing again as it is exported.

Accessing the data source through context bridge in preload script gives error. `Uncaught (in promise) Error: No metadata for "User" was found`

This is how I call the data source:

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('userRepository', {
  getUserAsync: async (userName: string) => {
    const userRepository = dbContext.getRepository(User);

    const user = await userRepository.findOne({where: {userName}});

    return user;
  },
});
```

It does work fine if I check if data source is initialized before db calls.  Should I use .destroy() method in the end of the methods as well? However, documentation says that  `Destroys the DataSource and closes all database connections. Usually, you call this method when your application is shutting down.` However, I do not think this is a correct usage.

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('userRepository', {
  getUserAsync: async (userName: string) => {
    if (!dbContext.isInitialized) {
      await dbContext.initialize();
    }
    const userRepository = dbContext.getRepository(User);

    const user = await userRepository.findOne({where: {userName}});

    return user;
  },
});
```

| Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Node.js version | 18.12.1 |
| Typescript version | 5.1.6 |
| TypeORM version | 0.3.17 |
| Electron version | 25.4.0 |